# What are the various ways of authenticating Logic app with "When an email received in Outlook.com" trigger?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have setup a logic app workflow which processes my emails whenever I receive them in my inbox folder. It then triggers the azure function and post the data to the some API endpoint.

Based on the status code from the azure function, it will move the email either to processed or failed folder which is defined in the **True** and **False** condition.
Please refer to snapshot  below:

[image]

Currently, I have logged in to the outlook using my personal email(see the highlighted part: abharati@......com.au). But it is being developed to monitor some other company's outlook account.
[image]
So, later when I deploy/host this workflow, I don't feel like it is an ideal to open the logic app designer window and ask the responsible person to authenticate by clicking on change connection link as shown in above picture which will prompt them to enter their outlook credentials and now the logic app will be monitoring their emails.

Is there any ideal way to achieve this?

Please let me know what is the best approach that the organization follows.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, I'm afraid we can't do it now in template. If already have some api connections with specified email account in resource group(because used them in logic app in the past), we can specify which api connection to use in template of logic app. Otherwise, we can't create and do authorization for o365 api connection in logic app template directly. Of course we also can't create the api connection when deploy the template of logic app.